# Tried to fix filesystem type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF and failed

Tags: macos, partition, filesystem, catalina, dual-boot

Initially, I had dual-booted Ubuntu on my Mac.
Several months later, I decided I no longer needed Ubuntu on my Mac so I decided to get rid of it. I attempted to this by using Disk Utility on macOS and erased the partition. It didn't work, only the swap partition was erased.

Afterwards, I've then accessed the Ubuntu version on my Mac, afterward, I found myself no longer able to access the Mac OS.

I found out that my mac partition had the same FFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFF problem as this post ([Partition type suddenly FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF, drive unmountable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239759/partition-type-suddenly-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-drive-unmountable))

I followed the instructions of the selected answer but now I can boot into neither of the OS (Before at least Linux was still bootable)

The current state of the machine is as the picture below:

[image]

My mac is a 2013 MacBook with 252 GB of SSD drive. It was running OS Catilina (the latest).

I'd really like to obtain my macOS back along with the data/files there.

Comment: You applied the wrong GUID at item2 and it probably has the wrong size. It has to be `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` instead of `4846...`. The main macOS system volume of Catalina is always formatted to APFS. Create a full bootable system (thumb drive/external drive) or attach it in Target Mode to another Mac and I will fix it from remote...with TeamViewer

Comment: @klanomath I've seen many of your answers from the previous posts but I didn't think you would see my question as well! I will get back to you once I've created a full bootable system, Thank you for your offer to help by the way!

Comment: Please send the TeamViewer credentials to klanomath(at)googlemail.com. Don't post them here!

Comment: @klanomath hey, I just recently you an email with the teamviewer credentials for my mac! Thanks again!