# Mac HD won't mount - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF Error

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, catalina, mount

Same error as a lot of users here, but I'm running Catalina, so I'm not sure if that changes things and I would rather make sure I'm going about it the right way so I don't make things worse.

I tried to delete a partition, and disk utility crashed halfway through. I restarted and got the folder with the ? on it.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me to fixing this without losing all of my data. Thanks.

E: I realise I should probably add a little more info. I have an Early 2013 15” MBP with the 500GB SSD.

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI: Since the output you posted from the command `gpt` has the message `/dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0` and the "question already has an answer" links do not, you will not be able to use any of these linked answers.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I found out that the GUID for the apple filesytem is the same across to the newest OS, so I was going to try and follow klanomath's instructions and use the GUID 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC that he provided.

Do you think I'll struggle with this suspicious MBR thing? Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/OaOHbRH) are the commands you need to enter to fix your Mac. These commands are based on klanomath's answer to the question [Partition type suddenly FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF, drive unmountable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239759/partition-type-suddenly-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-drive-unmountable). To enter these commands, you will need to first boot to macOS Internet Recovery or from a macOS Installation flash drive.  I assume you no longer want the 2 Linux partitions. If I am wrong, then let me know and I will update this answer.