# Partition type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF and drive unreachable

Tags: macos, partition, startup, apfs, dual-boot

I had Ubuntu dual booted on my 2015 MacBook Pro. I tried to remove the Ubuntu partition using Disk Utility, then when I attempted to delete the Linux partitons, it is completely gone out of sight. I was unable to regain that space to add it to my system. After a restart, the only boot option I see (holding the Option key) was EFI boot. Using the Internet Recovery Mode, I opened the terminal.

my `diskutil list` results were like this:

[image]

`gpt -r show disk0` result is as below:

[image]

It used to be named Macintosh HD (like the drive) and now it has lost its name and the partition type turned into FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF

I learned that I have to edit the partition table and modify the type of disk0s2 to get my main data partition back and make Boot OS X invisible. That's why I followed the guides to do that as in [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239766/372369)

As a result, I managed to modify the GUID type to Apple CORE storage (53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC):

[image]

When I tried to `diskutil verifyDisk disk0` and `diskutil repairDisk disk0`, i get an error.

[image]

I restarted the computer but still the only boot option I see was EFI boot.

What's the problem? What am I doing wrong? Please help me, it's very important for me to reach that disk having all my information inside.

Comment: Which macOS version was/is installed? It's rather a newer one and with an internal SSD drive and no Recovery partition present, I'd expect an APFS container (GUID: 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC) and not a CoreStorage container (GUID: 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECA). So simply remove the second partition and re-add it with `... -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC ...`!

Comment: @klanomath THANK YOU!!! I changed the GUID type to an APFS container and it worked. After restart, I opened the disk utility and reallocated free space. Everything is fine right now. Really appreciate your help. By the way, It's macOS 10.15.1.