# Disk unmounted showing in disk utility

Tags: macbook-pro, partition

I have installed Ubuntu os in my macbook Pro mid 2012 in 100gb partition storage. Today I want to delete that partition so I was using terminal for that but due to some mistakes by mac os get deleted and when I power on my macbook it shows question mark folder so I boot it in internet recovery mode but when I go to disk utility to first aid my disk it shows that disk0s2 is not mounted nothing happens when I click on Mount.... please help me what I have to do[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partition type suddenly FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF, drive unmountable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239759/partition-type-suddenly-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-drive-unmountable)

Comment: No...I'm not able to understand it